# Example of using GPS in AIR

Tags: mobile, air, gps

I'm looking to create a game using GPS in AIR for mobile devices. I've seen packaging and camera tutorials, but nothing using GPS yet. This question has a few parts:

1. Are there any GPS on AIR resource sites?

2. Any example code showing the accessing of GPS data in AIR (AS3)

3. Are there any ready-made libraries for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

not sure if you've done so, but you can read Adobe's official documentation on the [AIR Geolocation class (flash.sensors.Geolocation)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Geolocation.html), which includes example code.

a quick google search brought me to this geolocation tutorial:  http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3geolocation/, but it's a really simple, small class so the docs should be more than enough.

---

**EDIT:**

here is another good example for the geolocation class by adobe: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS144092a96ffef7cc-66bf4d0212658dde8c4-7fff.html

also this video, which additionally shows how to set specific permissions to access gps on Android:  http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/geo-location-api-for-adobe-air-on-android/

you can find more info about setting permissions on Android in the AIR 2.5 release notes:  http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/868/cpsid_86822.html